# Using Google Drive API, changed ownership to Hotmail account, can't change it back?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I was playing around with the Google Drive API for a work project, and was testing out what would happen if I attempted to insert a permission for an object that already existed.  In doing so (using the API reference pages), I overwrote the "reader" permission that I had granted to a Hotmail account to "owner" and that wound up demoting my actual GMail owner account to a writer.  So I'm now stuck with a file that I can't actually manage because I can't access Drive with a Hotmail account, nor can I authenticate with the Google Drive API with my Hotmail account.

A few notes:
- The Hotmail account is on my Google account as an alternate email address.
- When I use the links that were sent to my Hotmail address upon change, I get a view-only instance of the document.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Might be best to try and contact support.

Comment: Google API support is provided through stackoverflow, hence the post.

Comment: Thanks for the report @ctgilley. Are you able to reproduce this with another file? (a dummy/test file of course!)

Comment: @DanMcGrath - Yes, I was able to reproduce this with another Google Docs file that I created.  Used the insert permissions API to add my Hotmail address as an owner, and it switched ownership and demoted by Google account to writer.